# Is there any online version of the Kr̥ṣṇa-yajur-vedá Anu-krámaṇī available?

Tags: vedas, samhita, krishna-yajurveda

There seems to be an online version of the Şākala-saṁhitā́ Anu-krámaṇī, but I haven't had any luck finding an Anu-krámaṇī for the  Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́.

Is there an online version of the KYV Anu-krámaṇī available? If so, can anyone please link it?

Comment: Is [this](https://www.talentshare.org/~mm9n/articles/PDF/Krishna%20Yajur%20Veda.pdf) it?

Comment: @CDR Nope, that's Keith's translation of the Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́, not it's Anu-krámaṇī, which is a systematic listing of the mantra-s along with their chandas and ṛṣi.

Comment: Okay, I see. I hope someone finds it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Anu-krámaṇī of the Tāittirīya-Saṁhitā́ along with the Brāhmaṇá (including  the Kāṭhaka) and Āraṇyaká was compiled by S. Kulathu Hariharaputra Sharma under the name Krishna Yajurveda Taittireeya S'aakha Anubandha in 2015.

It can be accessed at https://uploadnow.io/f/zq5TxTg.

The second part of the Krishna Yajurveda Taittireeya S'aakha Anubandha was published in 2018 which can be accessed at https://uploadnow.io/f/nCJmtXX